# DocuSign - Can You Hide Recipient Signatures from other parties

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to find out if it is possible using the DocuSign API to create a signing request that is sent to multiple parties for signature with nobody seeing the other parties signatures until they have all signed?

Once all parties have signed I would download the final PDF and review this then send to all parties, but not sure if it's possible to hide these as it goes from one recipient to another?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one technique would be for each signer to have their own signature page for the document set. The signature page would actually be a separate document within the envelope. (But signers are not particularly aware of the fact that there can be multiple documents in an envelope since they all flow together.)

You'd use the document visibility feature so each signer would only see the main document(s) and their own signing page.

Try it out first via the web tool, [docs](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-visibility) within the developer sandbox. Then automate via the API.